# Como hacer un código en python y flask para generar etiquetas con códigos de barras para imprimir en impresora térmica?

Tags: python, flask, zpl

Lo que yo necesito es agregar a mi programa una función para generar códigos de barra, en particular PDF417 porque deben contener un link a una pagina web y los QR no me funcionan.
En si la etiqueta es muy simple, el problema mío es que no tengo una impresora donde probarlo y se me complica saber como avanzar.
Hasta donde llegue investigando para hacerlo lo mas general tengo que lograr crear un archivo ZPL, y lo puedo hacer mediante algunos paquetes de python o, dado que es tan simple podria armarlo como un string y guardarlo como archivo ".zpl". Abajo pego un codigo de ejemplo de como seria la etiqueta, solo deberia cambiar lo que esta en negrita entre una y la otra.

^XA

^FO5,5^BY3^B7N,5,0,1,2,4,N^FDwww.midominio.com/id/demo/**4**^FS

^FO120,130^A0N,30,30^FB300,1,0^FD**4**^FS

^XZ

Generar dinamicamente esa etiqueta es fácil, pero mis dudas son:

Si deseo imprimir 5 etiquetas (no iguales sino cambiando el numero en negrita), debo armar un único archivo ZPL con 5 bloques que empiecen con ^XA y terminen ^XZ considerando la medida de la etiqueta y la impresora interpreta que tiene que pasar a la siguiente etiqueta?

O tengo que armar un archivo ZPL considerando el tamaño del papel con las 5 etiquetas en el mismo bloque agregando coordenadas para que cada etiqueta quede en el lugar que le corresponde según su tamaño?